# Length of character array after fread is smaller than expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, fread

I am attempting to read a file into a character array, but when I try to pass in a value for MAXBYTES of 100 (the arguments are FUNCTION FILENAME MAXBYTES), the length of the string array is 7.

```
 FILE * fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fin == NULL) {                                                                                 
      printf("Error opening file \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    int readSize;

    //get file size
    fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int fileSize = ftell(fin);
    fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    if (argc < 3) {
      readSize = fileSize;
    } else {
      readSize = atof(argv[2]);
    }

    char *p = malloc(fileSize);     

    fread(p, 1, readSize, fin);
    int length = strlen(p);
    filedump(p, length);
```

As you can see, the memory allocation for p is always equal to filesize. When I use fread, I am trying to read in the 100 bytes (readSize is set to 100 as it should be) and store them in p. However, strlen(p) results in 7 during if I pass in that argument. Am I using fread wrong, or is there something else going on?

Thanks

Comment: Does the file contain text data? Or is it arbitrary binary data? If there are null bytes, `\x00`, then `strlen` will stop there.

Comment: And if the file *doesn't* contain a null byte somewhere, then the `strlen()` call will have undefined behavior.  Also, if the platform is Windows and the file contains a ^Z the read will stop at that point (since you didn't open it as a binary file).  If you want to know how many characters the `fread()` call reads, check what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the limitation with attempting to read text with `fread`. There is nothing wrong with doing so, but you must know whether the file contains something other than ASCII characters (such as the *nul-character*) and you certainly cannot treat any part of the buffer as a *string* until you manually *nul-terminate* it at some point.

`fread` does not guarantee the buffer will contain a *nul-terminating* character at all -- and it doesn't guarantee that the first character read will not be the *nul-character*.

Again, there is nothing wrong with reading an entire file into an allocated buffer. That's quite common, you just cannot treat what you have read as a *string*. That is a further reason why there are *character oriented*, *formatted*, and *line oriented* input functions. (`getchar`, `fgetc`, `fscanf`, `fgets` and POSIX `getline`, to list a few). The *formatted* and *line oriented* functions guarantee a *nul-terminated* buffer, otherwise, you are on your own to account for what you have read, and insure you nul-terminate your buffer -- before treating it as a string.